# Computer refused to turn off, now it doesn't POST

Tags: motherboard, bios, power-supply

Long story short my computer has the following symptoms:

- The whole computer stopped working in inactive mode when the screen had turned off. It didn't react to mouse movements or keyboard buttons.
- The power button didn't work, nothing happened when I held it in for several seconds. I had to turn off the computer with the PSU power button.
- Afterwards the computer refuses to POST or load BIOS.
- Some times the computer won't start until it's been disconnected from the power cable for some minutes.

What IS working:

- Fans are running and MB is lit up when the computer is started.
- Never had any high temperatures with this hardware.
- Power button works fine when starting the computer.

Hardware:

- Motherboard: Gigabyte GA-990 XA UD3
- Power supply: XFX Pro 1250w
- Can't find any extra PSU lying around.

What I've tried:

- All peripherals, graphics card, hard drives and RAM have been unplugged, doesn't change anything.
- CPU has been reseated, no change.
- CMOS replaced and reset, no change.

Question: Do I need a new motherboard?

Comment: Do you have the option to try a new PSU?

Comment: No, unfortunately I can't find any extra PSU'a lying around

Comment: Does the power button work to turn on the computer? After you disconnect the power for a bit of time when it is reconnected does the computer immediately start or does it only start when you press the power button. Might be a bad power button (dead in the closed position if the computer immediately starts when power is applied).

Comment: The power button works fine when starting the computer.
I also suspect that all the symptoms are connected, and a dead power button would not explain why the computer froze in inactive mode.

Answer (score 0):

After disassembling -everything- and putting it back together, suddenly everything works again. I still have noe idea why it stopped working, or why it works again.